# Reading registers with pymodbus

Tags: python, modbus

I am very new to Modbus and PyModBus however I have spent a good amount of time trying to read up and experiment with it.  If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it...

I have a drive with distance, velocity, acceleration, and deceleration on registers 40001, 40003, 40005, and 40007 (respectively).  I was initially able to write to the distance register, using client.write_register(0000, n).  After trying to write to velocity the drive started going haywire and faulting, and spinning 10x as fast as it should've been. However, the real priority is reading registers.  I am trying to read the data from these registers and having zero luck.  I tried using

```
request = client.read_holding_registers(0000,4)
response = client.execute(request)
print response
```

However, all I get back is "ReadRegisterResponse (0)".

So again, my big priority is trying to read values from these registers...any advice? (This is over TCP by the way)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to:

```
 response = client.read_holding_registers(0x00,4,unit=1)
```

where the unit value is device id of the slave.

To print all:

```
print response.registers
```

Also is possible to directly get one value (for example third register):

```
print response.getRegister(2)
```

or

```
print response.registers[2]
```

Comment: Where do you get the parameters `0x00,4` from if the OP wants to read at address 40000?

Comment: When I use .registers it works correctly in my case but I get a warning from PyCharm and it says "unresolved attribute reference 'registers' for class 'ModbusRespose'. Seems an error but the code works correctly... any idea?

Answer (score 5):

you could parse the response by yourself, the following is my code snippet:

```
    result = client.read_input_registers(0x01,1, unit=0x01)
    #print result
    t = result.registers[0]
    print "current temperature：", t, "  ", float(t/100.0)
```