# Using pymodbus to read registers

Tags: python, modbus-tcp

I'm trying to read modbus registers from a PLC using pymodbus. I am following the example posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872269/reading-registers-with-pymodbus). When I attempt `print.registers` I get the following error: `object has no attribute 'registers'`
The example doesn't show the modules being imported but seems to be the accepted answer. I think the error may be that I'm importing the wrong module or that I am missing a module. I am simply trying to read a register.

Here is my code:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient    
c = ModbusTcpClient(host="192.168.1.20")
chk = c.read_holding_registers(257,10, unit = 1)
response = c.execute(chk)
print response.registers
```

Comment: @J Earls The error is gone but not reading registers. Modbus Poll reads fine. Do you see anything else wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you ever tried to connect your modbus instance first?. c.connect() before read_holding_registers

Answer (score 2):

From reading [the pymodbus code](https://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/blob/master/pymodbus/register_read_message.py), it appears that the `read_holding_registers` object's `execute` method will return *either* a response object *or* an `ExceptionResponse` object that contains an error.  I would guess you're receiving the latter.  You need to try something like this:

```
from pymodbus.register_read_message import ReadHoldingRegistersResponse
#...
response = c.execute(chk)
if isinstance(response, ReadHoldingRegistersResponse):
  print response.registers
else:
  pass # handle error condition here
```